Record is not commited even if fully populated
I create a minimal code based upon the official example of QtModelUtilities library:
insertwhenalldone.h
#ifndef INSERTWHENALLDONE_H
#define INSERTWHENALLDONE_H

#include <InsertProxyModel>

class InsertWhenAllDone : public InsertProxyModel
{
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(InsertWhenAllDone)

public:
    explicit InsertWhenAllDone(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR) : InsertProxyModel(parent)
    {
    }

protected:
    bool validRow() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        if (!sourceModel()) return false;
        const int sourceCols = sourceModel()->columnCount();
        const int sourceRows = sourceModel()->rowCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceCols; ++i)
        {
            if (index(sourceRows, i).data().toString().isEmpty()) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool validColumn() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        if (!sourceModel()) return false;
        const int sourceCols = sourceModel()->columnCount();
        const int sourceRows = sourceModel()->rowCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceRows; ++i)
        {
            if (index(i, sourceCols).data().toString().isEmpty()) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

#endif // INSERTWHENALLDONE_H

myform.cpp
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("mydb");
QSqlTableModel *_model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
_model->setTable("mytable");
_model->select();

InsertWhenAllDone *insertProxy = new InsertWhenAllDone(this);
insertProxy->setSourceModel(_model);
insertProxy->setInsertDirection(InsertProxyModel::InsertDirection::InsertRow);
ui->table->setModel(insertProxy);

The expected behavior is:

there is always an empty row at the end of the table (OK)
if I fill only some cells of the empty row, nothing happens when I change row (OK)
if I fill all the fields, when I change row a new empty one should be added (OK) and the edited one must be saved (FAIL)

In fact, it appends a new empty row (not at the end, indeed - I bet this is due the issue itself), but the edited one is not committed to the db:

What

While the QtModelUtilities is a relatively popular library, it's hardly considered so common to justify asking such peculiar behavior that involves the special usage required by QtSql models. I'd suggest you to check their sources and eventually submit an issue on their repository.
